# Martha loves exercising so she ____ everywhere she goes

Tags: tense

> 1. Martha loves exercising so she **will walk** everywhere she goes.

Or is it...........

> 2. Martha loves exercising so she **walks** everywhere she goes.

I am terrible at grammar and I searched all over the net for help. I believe the answer is "walks". I just need to be sure.

Comment: In general I would use **walks**.  It's the simplest because the tenses match: Martha *loves* exercising (present tense) so she *walks* (present tense).

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical. Which one is correct depends on context, but 'walks' would be more common. E.g.

> Martha and Bill are both overweight and their doctor told them to lose
>   weight. Bill hates to exercise and will rely on diet, but Martha love
>   exercising so she will walk everywhere she goes.

because this is about something Martha will do in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct and understandable meaning

> Martha enjoys walking to get around

The slight difference is

> Martha loves exercising so she **walks**

sounds more like a **statement of fact**, this is what Martha does **repetitively and exclusively**

> Martha loves exercising so she **will walk**

has the feeling of Martha's preference to walk, but **not necessarily all the time**, by adding

> everywhere she goes

gives the context **repetition and exclusivity** and forces both sentences to have the same meaning.